# In PyPlot.jl, how do I get unicode characters to display properly?

Tags: unicode, julia, jupyter-notebook, ijulia-notebook

I am using Julia (with the IJulia plugin for Jupyter notebooks).  How do I get unicode characters to display correctly in my plot?

Here is my code:

```
using PyPlot
ϕ = linspace(-0.25, 1.25, 100);
f = (ϕ.^2).*(1.0-ϕ).^2;
figure(figsize=(8,5))
plot(ϕ, f, color="purple", linewidth=1.8, linestyle="-")
xlabel("ϕ")
ylabel("f(ϕ)")
```

However, the plot does not show the unicode character, ϕ, properly:

[image: plot]

Comment: Even the Pythonic `u'\phi'` doesn't work :(

Answer (score 7):

PyPlot support LaTeX commands, in this case:

```
xlabel(L"$\phi$")
ylabel(L"$f(\phi)$")
```

Comment: You can remove the dollar sign as it is not needed.